# CanvasJS - Adding wrong values on X axis (datetime) and line chart mistakes

Tags: canvasjs

I've made this chart using canvas.js, the problem is it shows data on april (it uses date and time as X axis) and there is no data for april.

It comes from a 3 month Bitcoin chart, it was too much data so i only left some days here, the chart looks ugly like this but it shows the problem perfectly. My complete charts also has some drawing problems but I assume it's al related to this data that went to april. See fiddle link.

```
enter code here (not sure why i'm asked to enter code when my code is in that fiddle)
```

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/K82z6/300/

Answer (score 0):

Ouch, month is cero based  when creating the date on canvasjs. Resolved.